# Can child activities access the same workflow extensions as their parent activities?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've got an extension that I add to WorkflowApplication.Extensions, the WorkflowApplication is pointing at a .xaml workflow (the parent) which calls another .xaml workflow (the child) during it's processing.

Question is; when I'm inside the the child .xaml workflow can I access said extension?

Get the feeling I'm missing something fundamental! :(

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the child is compiled and added as an activity to the main workflow it will see the same extensions.

If you start a new workflow, for example with the WorkflowInvoker, it will have it's own extensions. That said you can take extensions from the main workflow and add those to the child workflow as needed.

Comment: Hi Maurice, thanks for your quick response! That makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, a quick related question, say I have an extension to resolve dependencies and I want to use that extension when setting a default value for a variable in the child activity, how would I reference the extension when using the designer? Thx

Comment: Thx Will, I'm glad it's not me going stir crazy;)